# Capturing outgoing traffic from localhost MAMP using Wireshark

Tags: php, soap, wireshark, nusoap, network-monitoring

I'm trying to capture outgoing SOAP (over HTTP) requests generated by one of my PHP scripts (being run on my localhost). I'm running MAMP and using the PHP NuSOAP library for sending the request, I filter to HTTP traffic in Wireshark but nothing shows up when I run the script (which is sending a SOAP request to an external server via HTTP). Any ideas?

Thanks